# get and set reactive value within a v-for input field

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, v-model

I have a v-for loop that loops through properties of an object, it then renders key, value and index of the properties some of which are utilized within an input field. The object is populated dynamically when the user clicks a button. However, I cannot get the value within the input field to update the value of the property within the object of the vue instance that is dynamically populated, by use of the v-model directive. 
How do I get the input field's value to update the vue instance?

```
            <ul>
                <li v-for="(item, key, index) in itemsObj" v-if="item > 0">
                    {{ index }} - {{ key }} - <input type="number" v-model="item" min="1" max="5"> 
                    <div id="deleteItemID">
                        <button name="deleteItem" @click="deleteItem()" v-bind:value= key>X</button>
                    </div>
                </li>   
            </ul>
<button type="button" name="addToCart" @click="addToCart" id="prod" value="1">Add to Cart</button>
```

Then within the Vue instance

```
let shoppingCart = new Vue({
            el : '#shoppingApp',
            data : {
                totalItems : 0,
                itemsObj : {}
            }, 
            methods : {
                addToCart : function(){
                    let prodName = event.target.id;
                    let numberOfItems = parseInt(document.getElementById("prod").value);
                    this.updateItemsObj(this.itemsObj, prodName, numberOfItems);
                    this.$forceUpdate();
                },
              deleteItem : function(){
                    let x = event.target.value;
                    console.log(x);
                    this.updateItemsObj(this.itemsObj, x, 0);
                }
           }
})
enter code here
```

Comment: So, your only question here is how to get `v-model="item"` value inside `this.itemsObj`, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to access the `item` using `key`:

```
{{ index }} - {{ key }} - <input type="number" v-model="itemsObj[key]" min="1" max="5">
```

Also, remember that when adding properties dynamically you must use `Vue.set`

Answer (score 0):

You can handle `input` event on the input element and pass the key to the handler

```
<input type="number" :value="item" @input="onChange($event, key)" min="1" max="5">
```

and in the handler, you can do updates

```
onChange(event, key) {
  this.itemsObj[key] = event.target.value;
}
```